# How to filter Grouping Grid in Each Group ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

I am creating a Grouping Grid. Here am following these steps:

1. Store has all records
2. OnLoad of grid am filtering Store, so am getting all filter data for each group & displaying under corresponding group.
3. Here All Groups are expanded with filter data and the Icon is "-", but I want the icon should show "+" Icon. So that when I will expand or click on the groupName it will show all records of that group.

Let's say there are 5 records under a group and when Grid loaded it displayed 2 filtered record with "+" icon. So when I click on the GroupName / + icon it should display 5 records.

Basically looking for Group filteration and at collapsed condition it should display the filtered data.

Appreciate your answers & thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can get the current grouping field and its value. After this you can filter the store accordingly. Hope it helps or post code sample.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: We are here to help each other and provide some direction not to provide exact customized solutions.